# How to use oneOf in JSON Schema to ensure that certain fields of a JSON file are not required

Tags: json, validation, jsonschema

I have a JSON schema that defines disease notification data. In my case, I want to store the data of the disease and the patient's hospitalization data. If the patient who contracted the disease was hospitalized (`"hospitalized ": 1`) I need to write the hospital's name too, but if the patient was not hospitalized (`"hospitalized": 2`) I don't need to have the hospital name. That's my JSON Schema

```
{
 "$schema":"http://json-schema.org/draft-04/schema#",
 "title": "Notification",
 "description": "Information about disease notification",
 "type": "object",

 "properties":{

     "classification":{
         "enum":[1,2,3,4]
     },

     "evolution":{
        "enum":[1,2]
    },

    "hospitalization":{

        "description":"Patient hospitalization data",
        "type":"object",

        "oneOf":[

        {"$ref":"#/definitions/hospitalized_schema"},
        {"$ref":"#/definitions/not_hospitalized_schema"}

        ]
    }
},

"definitions":{

    "hospitalized_schema:":{

        "type":"object",

        "properties":{

            "hospitalized":{

                "enum":[1]

            },

            "hospital":{

                "description":"Hospital name",
                "type":"string"
            }

        },

        "required":["hospitalized","hospital"]
    },

    "not_hospitalized_schema":{

        "type":"object",

        "properties":{

            "hospitalized":{
                "enum":[2]
            }
        },

        "required":["hospitalized"]
    }   
},

"required":["classification","evolution","hospitalization"]
}
```

The JSON Schema has been validated on the site [JSON Schema Lint](http://jsonschemalint.com/draft4/). But I am having trouble validating the following JSON files:

```
{ 
    "classification":3,
    "evolution":2,
    "hospitalization": {
        "hospitalized":2
    }
}
```

In this case a I get the `no (or more than one) schemas match` error, but I would like it to be valid, because as the patient wasn't hospitalized, the `hospitalized` value must be 2.

My second JSON file is

```
{ 
    "classification":3,
    "evolution":2,
    "hospitalization": {
        "hospitalized":1,
        "hospital":"Hospital Name"
    }
}
```

This JSON file is validated correctly, but if I change the value of `hospitalized` to 2 the file still valid, but it's not true because since the patient was not hospitalized (`"hospitalized": 2`) my JSON file should not have the `hospital` field.

How can I fix these errors? That is, ensure that when the `hospitalized` field is 1, the field`hospital` is necessary and when the `hospitalized` field is 2, the `hospital` field is not necessary.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The reason your first test case isn't working is simply due to a typo at `#/definitions/hopitalized_schema`.  It says `hospitalized_schema:` instead of `hospitalized_schema`.  When you delete the extra `:`, it works as expected.

As for your second test case, I would advise you not to consider having the `hospital` field present an error.  The best practice when working with JSON and JSON Schema is to ignore any additional properties that you aren't interested in.  In this case, `hospital` is not relevant and therefore should be ignored.

However, if it really is important that the `hospital` property is not present when `hospitalized` is `2`, you can add `"not": { "required": ["hospital"] }` to `#/definitions/not_hospitalized_schema` to explicitly require that it not be present.

Comment: Thanks! Using "not": { "required": ["hospital"] } ( and removing the extra ':' ) totally solved my problem.